# Solidity state variable resets to default inside function

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

For this project, I am coding smart contracts for Ethereum using Solidity.

In the following code, the variable `numCertificates` should initially be 1. Nonetheless, newCertificateId is 0 when assigned. According to the debugger (I'm using remix.ethereum.org), for some reason, numCertificates becomes 0 as soon as the line where newCertificateId is assigned is reached.

I have played around with remix a lot, and according to it, numCertificates is 1 until exactly the aforementioned line is reached. Also, I think that if I modify numCertificates in another function, the variable stays the same as before.

My attempts at trying to figure this out lead me to believe that when I access numCertificates, I am not accessing the public state variable but something else.

Why does this code have this problem and how can it be solved?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract MyToken {
    // ... lots of irrelevant stuff here
    mapping (uint64 => Certificate) public certificates;
    uint64 numCertificates = 1;

    // ... lots of irrelevant stuff here

    function MyToken() public {
      // ... likely irrelevant code
    }

    function produceCertificate(
      // ... likely irrelevant parameters
      ) public {
        // Create the certificate in memory
        numCertificates;// only for debbuging
        Certificate storage newCertificate = constructCertificate(meterId, timestamp, carbonMitigationValue, owner);
        uint64 newCertificateId = numCertificates;
        newCertificate.certificateId = newCertificateId;

        // Save the certificate
        certificates[newCertificateId] = newCertificate;
        numCertificates++;
    }



    function constructCertificate(
      uint64 meterId,
      uint32 timestamp,
      uint48 value,
      address owner
      ) internal returns (Certificate storage newCertificate) {
        newCertificate.meterId = meterId;
        newCertificate.timestamp = timestamp;
        newCertificate.value = value;

        newCertificate.owners.push(owner);
        newCertificate.ownershipSplit[owner] = value;

        newCertificate.burned = false; // by default new certificates are fresh

        return newCertificate;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably in `constructCertificate`. Just a hunch, but do you get a warning from the compiler somewhere in there about an uninitialized storage reference?

Comment: I would suggest changing `storage` to `memory` in `Certificate storage newCertificate = ...` and the return type of `constructCertificate`. That's the best help I can give without seeing the code.

Comment: @smarx I do not get any warnings, no

Comment: @smarx I will try that. I used storage because the certificates are stored in the state. I am updating the question now to include more details of constructCertificate.

Comment: Seeing the implementation of that function, I'm confident that's the issue. I can explain better tonight when I'm back at a computer. :-)

Comment: Changing newCertificate to memory brings problem with newCertificate.owners.push() and newCertificate.ownershipSplit[owner]

Comment: @smarx I love you. I ended up setting the what's possible to the memory certificate, then I stored it in storage, and finally made the maps and arrays by creating a storage variable referencing the storage certificate and accessing the map and array through it.